# What is the scriptural reference of the 'Dadhivamana' Form of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, puranas

What is the source of the 'Dadhi-VAmana' Form of Sri Vishnu? Why did He take this particular Form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lord Viṣṇu took the form of Vāmana to subdue the pride of King Mahābali Cakravarti.

Dadhi, is the Sanskrit word for curd. [(Source for the translation)](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=dadhi&direct=se)

> दधि (n.) dadhi - curd

It is believed that offerings of curd and curd-rice are very dear to Lord Vāmana. Hence, the name Dadhi Vāmana.

It is interesting to note that there is also a Sālagrama Mūrtī called [Dadhi Vāmana Sālagrama](https://shaligrama.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/vamana-dadhi-rakta-nila.jpg).

This Sālagrama Mūrtī, aptly has small white spots on it. These are identified as tiny dots of curd.

The Mantra for this Sālagrama reads:

> Ardhascakrāgra Vilasad 
>   **Dadhibindu Samāyutam** 
>   Vāmanam Raktanīlābham 
>   Vadanti Dadhivāmanam
>
> With a half-Cakra on the top, and **having spots of curd on it**, Vāmana, with with a reddish and bluish hue, they say, is DadhiVāmana.

There is also a Mantra to this form of Vāmana called DadhiVāmana, called the DadhiVāmana Stotram. You can find it at http://www.hithokthi.com/viewstotra.php?g_id=8&cat_id=1&story_id=229

The only reference to DadhiVāmana I could find, is in the sixth volume of [Pratima Kōśā](https://archive.org/details/PratimaKosaEncyclopediaOfIndianIconographyRamachandraRaoS.K.Vol6_201712/page/n118), which is a six-volume book on Hindu Iconography (pg.108-109), which further mentions the ***Meru-tantra***, the ***Sāradā-tilaka*** and the ***Mantra-devatā-prakāśikā*** :

In the Pratima Kōśā, it is written:

> Several forms of Vāmana are mentioned as for instance Dadhi-Vāmana (***Meru-tantra 26, 341-342, and Sāradā-tilaka, 15, 56-60***). In Tantra, he is derived from the conception of ‘dadhi’(curds) as the creative principle of life. In ***Meru-tantra*** Dadhi-Vāmana is visualised as
>   seated upon a red lotus under the parasol of golden rays, lustrous like the full moon (**’Jvalan Mayūkha Kanakaccatrādhah Puṇdarīka-gam**) holding in his right hand a golden bowl filled with cooked rice mixed with curds (**’Dadhyannam Vāma-hastena Svarṇasya-Cakśakam Dadhat**).
>
> ***Mantra-devatā-prakāśikā (cited in Prapanca-sāra-sāra-sangraha, Tanjore, Vol II, patala 31, pg. 904)*** which also mentions that Dadhi-Vāmana, makes him reside in the lunar orb (**Candra-samstha**) and hold in his two hands, a golden jar of pure water (**Kanaka-kalaśam Śuddha-toyābhipūrṇam)**, and a golden bowl filled with cooked rice mixed in curds (**’Dadhyannādhyam Kanaka-Cakśakam**).